# For loop output in jframe

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jframe

So this is for my school assignment

Write a program that:
Accepts input of a starting value.
Accepts input of an ending value.
Displays all the integers (inclusive) between those two values.
Hint: Use a for loop and don't forget to convert the input from a string to an integer.

Its written in a jFrame and it only outputs the last value instead of all the values in between the starting and ending value. I'm using netbeans IDE 8.0.

```
//Variables
int starting, ending;
starting=Integer.parseInt(this.txtStarting.getText());
ending=Integer.parseInt(this.txtEnding.getText());

//for Loop
for(int output=starting; output < ending; output++) {
    String out1 = Integer.toString(output);
    this.lblValues.setText(out1);
}
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong. When I `System.out.println(output);` it outputs what I want how I want it.

Comment: The method `setText` sets the text. It doesn't append to the existing text.

Comment: Write it out to a JTextArea, appending the text as you go via `myTextArea.append(out1 + "\n");`

Comment: How do I add the correct text to the jLabel?

Comment: **DON'T USE A JLABEL**.  Again, use a JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

When you call setText(), you are setting the text in the JLabel (I assume that's the type of lblValues).  Previous values are not being stored.  You could fix this by appending to a string then just setting the text at the end:

```
String out1 = "";
for(int output=starting; output <= ending; output++) {
    out1 = out1 + " " + Integer.toString(output);
}
this.lblValues.setText (out1);
```

Also note that you need output <= ending, not output < ending, as the condition for your for loop, otherwise the last value won't be included.

Comment: Use [string builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) because you're creating a big performance issue.